# order of sum then cumsum in different dimensions matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, cumsum, operator-precedence

I have 3 3d matrices `ty_trans`, `ty_trans_gm` and `ty_trans_submeso` that include `NaN`s. I'm making `psi` (which *ignores* `NaN`s) from them using two methods which I think should be the same, but aren't and I can't figure out why.

```
psinew = squeeze(nansum(nancumsum(ty_trans,3)+ty_trans_gm+ty_trans_submeso,1));

psiold = squeeze(nancumsum(nansum(ty_trans,1),3)+nansum(ty_trans_gm+ty_trans_submeso,1));
```

Where `nancumsum` is essentially `cumsum` where `NaN` is treated like a `0` (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14895-nancumsum).

I know `psiold` is the *right* option for `psi` between `psinew` and `psiold`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect `cumsum(sum())` to be the same as `sum(cumsum())`?

Comment: Those operations are not interchangeable.  Consider a counterexample where the input is `A = [1 2 3 4 5];`.  Doing `cumsum(sum(A)) = cumsum(15) = 15;` whereas `sum(cumsum(A)) = sum([1 3 6 10 15]) = 35`.